# Deploying Liferay on Cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

I'd like to deploy Liferay on Cloudbees. I found [this blog '15 minutes to liferay on cloudbees paas'](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2011/09/15-minutes-to-liferay-on-cloudbees-paas.html) with instructions on how to do it. I followed all those instructions, and the actual deployment seemed to go fine. There are no error messages in the logs either. But when I click the link that should lead to my site (with Liferay on it), I get the message that the resource isn't available. Does anyone have any clues what I might have done wrong?

My own guess is that I don't have the right values in portal-ext.properties, so here it is:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.cloudbees.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:cloudbees://liferay_db/liferay_db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=MyUserName
jdbc.default.password=MyPassword
#lucene.store.type=ram
#lucene.store.jdbc.auto.clean.up.enabled=true
```

**[update]**
I have now tried the Liferay Clickstart. Now I get a '502 Bad gateway' when I access the site. But at least this time there are error messages in the logs:

```
19:17:03,413 ERROR [main][JDBCExceptionReporter:76] Table 'liferay-po-12.portalpreferences' doesn't exist
19:17:03,565 ERROR [main][FileChecker:123] 
com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException:  
com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: 
com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at 
com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.processException(BasePersistenceImpl.java:193)
at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.PortalPreferencesPersistenceImpl.fetchByO_O(PortalPreferencesPersistenceImpl.java:600)
at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.PortalPreferencesPersistenceImpl.fetchByO_O(PortalPreferencesPersistenceImpl.java:519)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.PortalPreferencesLocalServiceImpl.doGetPreferences(PortalPreferencesLocalServiceImpl.java:170)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.PortalPreferencesLocalServiceImpl.getPreferences(PortalPreferencesLocalServiceImpl.java:101)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.PortalPreferencesLocalServiceImpl.getPreferences(PortalPreferencesLocalServiceImpl.java:88)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:122)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLAdvice.invoke(PACLAdvice.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
at $Proxy67.getPreferences(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.service.PortalPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPreferences(PortalPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.java:282)
at com.liferay.portal.util.PrefsPropsUtil.getPreferences(PrefsPropsUtil.java:250)
at com.liferay.portal.util.PrefsPropsUtil.getPreferences(PrefsPropsUtil.java:241)
at com.liferay.portal.util.PrefsPropsUtil.getString(PrefsPropsUtil.java:448)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.DeployUtil.getAutoDeployDestDir(DeployUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.DeployManagerImpl.getInstalledDir(DeployManagerImpl.java:60)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.DeployManagerUtil.getInstalledDir(DeployManagerUtil.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.checker.FileChecker.afterPropertiesSet(FileChecker.java:119)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.BasePACLPolicy.initChecker(BasePACLPolicy.java:111)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.BasePACLPolicy.initCheckers(BasePACLPolicy.java:146)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.BasePACLPolicy.<init>(BasePACLPolicy.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.InactivePACLPolicy.<init>(InactivePACLPolicy.java:32)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLPolicyManager.<clinit>(PACLPolicyManager.java:200)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLAdvice.invoke(PACLAdvice.java:47)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
at $Proxy48.clear(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.service.LockLocalServiceUtil.clear(LockLocalServiceUtil.java:267)
at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.doRun(StartupAction.java:75)
at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:52)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processStartupEvents(MainServlet.java:1306)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:214)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
at com.staxnet.appserver.TomcatServerBase.startContainer(TomcatServerBase.java:120)
at com.staxnet.appserver.TomcatServerBase.start(TomcatServerBase.java:190)
at com.staxnet.appserver.StaxAppServer.main(StaxAppServer.java:89)
at com.staxnet.appserver.SnazAppServer.main(SnazAppServer.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at net.stax.appserver.bootstrap.Bootstrap.invokeAppServerMain(Bootstrap.java:41)
at net.stax.appserver.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:30)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.ExceptionTranslator.translate(ExceptionTranslator.java:30)
at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:98)
at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:75)
at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.PortalPreferencesPersistenceImpl.fetchByO_O(PortalPreferencesPersistenceImpl.java:575)
... 65 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2545)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:940)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:86)
... 67 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'liferay-po-12.portalpreferences' doesn't exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
... 74 more
19:17:04,035 ERROR [main][JDBCExceptionReporter:76] Table 'liferay-po-12.lock_' doesn't exist
```

There was also a message about a log file being non-existing:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/liferay/logs/liferay.2012-09-17.log (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:192)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
at org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.activateOptions(RollingFileAppender.java:179)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:295)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1001)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:867)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:815)
at com.liferay.util.log4j.Log4JUtil.configureLog4J(Log4JUtil.java:79)
at com.liferay.util.log4j.Log4JUtil.configureLog4J(Log4JUtil.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.util.InitUtil.init(InitUtil.java:99)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
at com.staxnet.appserver.TomcatServerBase.startContainer(TomcatServerBase.java:120)
at com.staxnet.appserver.TomcatServerBase.start(TomcatServerBase.java:190)
at com.staxnet.appserver.StaxAppServer.main(StaxAppServer.java:89)
at com.staxnet.appserver.SnazAppServer.main(SnazAppServer.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at net.stax.appserver.bootstrap.Bootstrap.invokeAppServerMain(Bootstrap.java:41)
at net.stax.appserver.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:30)
```

[/update]

Comment: can you please post the complete error message ?

Comment: That's the problem, there is no complete error message. I simply get a 404.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the newly created ClickStart for Liferay, which you can find here:
https://github.com/CloudBees-community/liferay-clickstart

You would have to click the "Deploy instantly on CloudBees" button, and there are two modifications to be done before it can run properly (And maybe those were the reason why it didn't work originally for you, as Tomcat will return "resource not available" if it runs out of PermGen space)

- Set a bigger PermGen space with:

  ```
  bees app:update ACCOUNT/APP_NAME jvmPermSize=256
  ```
- Change the size of your application with the CloudBees web management console to the recommended 1024MB for Liferay.

Comment: Wow, they're really fast at Cloudbees! This feature was only thought of last week!